# SpriteKit SKAction moveTo: distorted when app goes to background

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction

In a SpriteKit game, I am using a forever repeating `SKAction moveTo:` to display metal shine/shimmer on a sprite. It's basically an `SKCropNode` mask that moves from one position to another, pauses, moves back to it's starting position, and repeats. The `maskNode` itself animates in the reverse direction.

This works fine, even with hundreds of them on the screen running for hours.

However, when the app goed to the background and comes back, all the positions of these nodes have changed. The animations still continue, but at the wrong positions. Metal shimmer everywhere on the screen, except where it should be.

I am not changing anything in the `UIApplication` delegate methods. Even if I `pause` the `SKView` while the app is in the background, the exact same thing happens.

```
// create the shine node
    SKSpriteNode *shine = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:@"metal_shine"];
    shine.size = self.size;

// create the mask node
    SKSpriteNode *maskNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:@"disk_mask"]];
    maskNode.size = self.size;

// create the crop node
    SKCropNode *cropNode = [[SKCropNode alloc] init];
    [cropNode addChild:shine];
    cropNode.maskNode = maskNode;
    cropNode.maskNode.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.5, self.size.height * -0.5);
    cropNode.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width * -0.5, self.size.height * 0.5);
    [self addChild:cropNode];
    
// add actions
    SKAction *delayAction = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.0];
    SKAction *pauseAction = [SKAction waitForDuration:3.0];

    SKAction *resetActionMaskNode = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.5, self.size.height * -0.5) duration:0];
    SKAction *moveActionMaskNode = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.size.width * -0.5, self.size.height * 0.5) duration:0.6];
    SKAction *resetActionCropNode = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.size.width * -0.5, self.size.height * 0.5) duration:0];
    SKAction *moveActionCropNode = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.5, self.size.height * -0.5) duration:0.6];
    
    SKAction *repeatActionMaskNode = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[resetActionMaskNode, moveActionMaskNode, pauseAction]]];
    SKAction *repeatActionCropNode = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[resetActionCropNode, moveActionCropNode, pauseAction]]];


// go
    [cropNode.maskNode runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[delayAction, repeatActionMaskNode]] withKey:@"idleAnimation"];
    [cropNode runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[delayAction, repeatActionCropNode]] withKey:@"idleAnimation"];
```

Comment: I think the problem is with ```(self.position.x + self.size.width * 0.5, self.position.y - self.size.height * 0.5)``` - what does ```self``` refer to? Maybe store the position and size and not get it from ```self```?

Comment: @skaak thank you that was indeed wrong. `self` refers to the sprite that the effect is added to as a child. However, after fixing that the problem still exists; after app goes to background and comes back, the `position.x` of both the `cropNode` and the `maskNode` are suddenly offset.

Comment: Ok - here you just show the inside. When do you call this or inside what message is this?